# Как создать generic-метод, принимающий один из двух классов?

Tags: java, generics

Есть метод, который должен принимать один из двух классов:

```
private <T extends First | Second> Ret method(T obj); //хотел но не работает
```

Проблема в том что и `First` и  `Second` это классы у которых нет общего родителя. Это сгенерированые `wsdl` данные «сверху». Сейчас у меня два одинаковых метода:

```
private Ret method(First obj)

private Ret method(Second obj)
```

с одинаковым телом.

Хочу решить проблему при помощи дженерика.

Comment: Можете уточнить что делает `method`? Он обращается к каким-то методам, общим для `First` и `Second`?

Comment: @default locale да меноды у First и Second одинаковые ну это просто переливание данных. Зачем их два не знаю. Это сочинял не я.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23769208/4928642 - интересная идея :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5196941/4928642 - вот как-то так :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ИЛИ* для обобщений не работает, к сожалению. Единственное, что в такой ситуации приходит в голову, это объявить в этом же классе приватный метод принимающий `T extends Object`, перенести в него логику и вызывать его из `method(First obj)` и `method(First obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже ответили, обобщенные методы в Java не поддерживают такого рода ограничения.

Если есть возможность изменять код `First` и `Second`, то можно вынести методы, к которым обращается `method` в общий интерфейс/класс-родитель и написать один метод, принимающий данный интерфейс.

Если такой возможности нет, то можно попробовать [обернуть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) `First` и `Second` в классы, которые будут реализовывать интерфейс с общими методами.

Примитивный пример для одного общего метода:

```
class First {
     //общий метод
     void save() {...}
}

class Second {
     void save() {...}
}

//создаем интерфейс
interface Saveable {
     void save();
}
//класс-обертка для First
class FirstSaveableWrapper implements Saveable {
     private final First first;
     FirstSaveableWrapper(First first) {
         this.first = first;
     }
     @Overrides
     public void save() {
         first.save();
     }
}

//аналогичный класс для Second
class SecondSaveableWrapper implements Saveable {
     ...
}

//общий метод
Ret method(Saveable obj) {
     ...
     obj.save();
}

//перегруженные методы для First и Second
Ret method(First first) {
     return method(new FirstSaveableWrapper(first));
}
Ret method(Second second) {
     return method(new SecondSaveableWrapper(second));
}
```

Так мы уменьшим масштабы дублирования кода до вызова отдельных методов. Насколько оправдана такая борьба с дублированием зависит от того, сколько у `First` и `Second` общих методов и какова вероятность того, что логика `method` будет изменяться для обоих классов/для каждого класса в отдельности.

В зависимости от ситуации можно заменить явно объявленные классы-обертки на анонимные классы, реализующие интерфейс:

```
Ret method(First first) {
     return method(new Saveable(first){
         void save() {
              first.save();
         }
     });
}
```

Либо, вынести каждый метод в отдельный интерфейс и использовать лямбда-выражения/ссылки на методы.

Answer (score 2):

А так не годится: делаем двух наследников, у которых указан общий интерфейс и используем вместо оригинальных классов наследников: https://ideone.com/RLYP61

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
  static class First { public void doSmth() { System.out.println("First"); } }
  static class Second { public void doSmth() { System.out.println("Second"); } }

  static interface DoSmth { void doSmth(); }
  static class FirstWrapper extends First implements DoSmth {}
  static class SecondWrapper extends Second implements DoSmth {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    doSmth(new FirstWrapper());
    doSmth(new SecondWrapper());
  }

  public static void doSmth(DoSmth smth) {
    smth.doSmth();
  }
}
```

Comment: Отличный вариант, +1! Но еще нужно чтобы wrapper-ы принимали оригинальные объекты в конструктор и делегировали им вызовы методов, ведь наверняка у них есть какое-то состояние.

Comment: @defaultlocale, так у меня он них наследовние - принимать в конструктор и делигировать уже описали в соседнем ответе.